# How to make array of images using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am making a site.
In that site I want to do some cool transition of images as like the one in the link given below:

http://www.menucool.com/slider/javascript-image-slider-demo2

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: And you want we create your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to write the steps.

`1.` Download the archive on http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider.

`2.` Check files and try one demo which is include.

`3.` Clean up this demo to keep only the structure menu

`4.` Add the HTML menu on your website.

`5.` Add link to CSS and jQuery plugIn menu on the head of your website.

`6.` Come back in this post if you have any problem.

Comment: can u help me out with one more thing..
that is..
i want to make a main <div> in my site like the below link given
http://www.ankitfadia.in/
like there is a box coming on the toop of the whole website..
I want to make that type of box...which is coming over the main website..and making the rest of the website blurryyy...
Please Help me out with this..

Comment: If you want an another example please let me know..

Comment: You want the modal box when you coming on the website? This box which is center forward with the content website behind in black?

Comment: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/ Use this website, it's very good demonstration and you have different types http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/. Pass your post solved. Good Luck :)

Comment: hey Donovan Charpin that was really helpfull thanks buddy..:)

Comment: hey can you tell me some good refernece for making cool tansition or anything which makes my site eye catchy for other people.. in the website
like some pdf of a wesite from where i could learn..